# Linear Regression Point Estimates

Tags: regression, variance

Suppose we construct the linear relation (using least squares)

$$\text{Weight} = \text{Height}\cdot b + c$$

As I recall from school 30 years ago, Weight is normally distributed with the mean of E(Weight) and Var(Weight).  The model gives us our point estimate of Weight, but what is the estimate of Var(Weight)?

Also, how might you go about extending this to a model with multiple independent variables?

Comment: Weight isn't really normally distributed. There are, for example, people that are more than double the average weight, but there aren't any that are as far the other direction (even a brain-in-a-jar would weigh a bit). Also weight isn't really linearly related to height; people have three dimensions, they're not like rods of uniform thickness.

Comment: Further, the model isn't $y=\beta x$. Even if you're fitting a model without an intercept, the model is $y=\beta x + \varepsilon$. If you don't include an error term it implies that you think height is always exactly a scaled weight, with the same scaling constant. You'd only need one data point to know the value of the population $\beta$ exactly...

Comment: But the estimates from a linear regression will tend to be normal

Comment: oops, and I did leave out the constant.  Sorry :(

Comment: Estimates might indeed be more near to normal than the conditional response (they still can't be actually normal, since they're linear combinations of things we know to be non-normal) but I was referring to the phrase "*Weight is normally distributed*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the regression model is a model for the conditional distribution of $y$. So if you're modelling Weight, it doesn't tell you about $E(\text{Weight})$ or $\text{Var}(\text{Weight})$, but the conditional expectation and conditional variance (i.e. $E(\text{Weight}|\text{Height})$ and $\text{Var}(\text{Weight}|\text{Height})$).

If you construct a linear model you estimate variance about the model from the model fit.

Specifically, the usual estimate of $\sigma^2 = \text{Var}(Y|X=x)$ is

$$\hat{\sigma}^2=s^2=\frac{1}{n-p}\sum_i(y_i-\hat{y}_i)^2\,.$$

In the above equation, $p$ is the number of predictors including the constant, so for simple linear regression, $p=2$. This equation applies just as well to cases where $X$ contains several variables.

The square root of that variance estimate, the residual standard deviation (sometimes called 'residual standard error'), $s$, is available in the output of any decent regression package.

Here's some output from R, for example (I cut out a few extraneous lines):

```
>  summary(lm(dist~speed,cars))
[...]
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -17.5791     6.7584  -2.601   0.0123   
speed         3.9324     0.4155   9.464 1.49e-12 
---    
Residual standard error: 15.38 on 48 degrees of freedom   
Multiple R-squared:  0.6511,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6438 
F-statistic: 89.57 on 1 and 48 DF,  p-value: 1.49e-12
```

As we see on the third-last line, $s=15.38$. (The [data set `cars`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/cars.html) comes with R.)

Or we can compute it by hand:

```
> r <- residuals(lm(dist~speed,cars))
> sqrt(sum(r^2)/48)   # n=50, p=2, so we divide by 48
[1] 15.37959
```

You can do similar calculations in your favourite stats program, or even something like Excel.